# Show that each character of $G$ which is zero for all $g \ne 1$ is an integral multiple of the character $r_G$ of the regular representation

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, representation-theory, characters

This is a question from J.P.Serre's book 'Linear representation of finite groups',section 2.4

The question: Let $G$ be a finite group. Show that each character of $G$ which is zero for all $g \ne 1$ is an integral multiple of the character $r_G$ of the regular representation.

What I have done so far:
$r_G$ satisfies $r_G(g) = 0$ for all $g \ne 1$, and $r_G(1) = |G|$, the order of $G$. If $\chi$ denotes the character, then $\chi(g) = r_G(g) = 0$ for all $g \ne 1$, so it is enough to show that $|G|$ divides $\chi(1)$. If $\chi_1,...,\chi_k$ denotes all the irreducible characters of $G$, with dimension of the representations $n_1,...,n_k$ respectively, then we can write
$\chi = \sum_{i=1}^k \langle \chi,\chi_i\rangle \chi_i$, where $\langle \chi,\chi_i\rangle$ is the inner product. And it is easy to calculate $\langle \chi,\chi_i\rangle = (\chi(1)/|G|)\,n_i$. So each of these values must be integers for all $i$.
But how does one conclude that in fact $\chi(1)/|G|$ is an integer?

thanks in advance.

Comment: [Please see here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/5020/264) for how to typeset common math expressions with LaTeX, and [see here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/editing-help) for how to use Markdown formatting.

Comment: Thank you! I don't know LaTeX, so sorry for my cumbersome notations.

Comment: Note, that the trivial representation is irreducible and one-dimensional.

Comment: @martini : Can you please give some more details? I can't see why it is important here.

Comment: @usersujo Let $\chi_k$ be the character of a one-dimensional representation then $n_k = 1$. By your Argument above $\langle \chi, \chi_k\rangle = \chi(1)/|G|\cdot n_k = \chi(1)/|G|$ is an integer.

Comment: @martini : Thank you very much! I completely overlooked the fact that ttrivial representation belongs to one of the irreducible representations of G.

Comment: @martini Please consider converting your comment into an answer, so that this question gets removed from the [unanswered tab](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/3138). If you do so, it is helpful to post it to [this chat room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/9141) to make people aware of it (and attract some upvotes). For further reading upon the issue of too many unanswered questions, see [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/143113), [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/1148) or [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/9868).

Comment: @JulianKuelshammer done.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

One of the irreducible representations is the trivial, one-dimensional one, say $\chi_i$ is its character. Then $n_i = 1$, and your argument above gives 
$\def\<#1>{\left\langle#1\right\rangle}$that $$\<\chi, \chi_i> = \chi(1)/|G| \cdot n_i = \chi(1)/|G| $$
is an integer.

Answer (score 6):

I think it's worth pointing out that we don't need to know that $\chi$ can be decomposed as above, which is something that Serre proves in the next section after this exercise. By direct computation, the (integer!) number of times that the representation that has $\chi$ as its character contains the trivial representation $1$ is $\langle \chi,1\rangle$:
$$
\langle \chi,1\rangle = \frac{1}{|G|}\sum_{s\in G}\chi(s^{-1})1(s) = \frac{1}{|G|}\chi(1) \ne 0.
$$
Moving $|G|$ to the other side, we get $\chi(1) = \langle\chi,1\rangle\cdot|G| = \langle\chi,1\rangle\cdot r_G(1)$. Hence $\chi = \langle\chi,1\rangle\cdot r_G$ since $\chi(s) = r_G(s) = 0$ if $s\ne 1$.